# Razor component value not updating inside LocationChanged event handler

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-7.0, blazor-component

`Razor component` value is not updating inside `LocationChanged` event handler.

I have created a Razor component `Breadcrumb.razor`. I'm using this component inside my `MainLayout.razor` page.

I need to update my breadcrumb values on `Navigation.LocationChanged` event which is invoking fine when I navigate. But the problem is my values are not updating.

```
@inject NavigationManager Navigation
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <ol class="breadcrumb bg-transparent mb-0 pb-0 pt-1 px-0 me-sm-6 me-5">
        @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Module) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Function))
        {
            <li class="breadcrumb-item text-sm text-dark active"><i class="fa fa-home text-primary"></i> Dashboard</li>
        }else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Module) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Function))
        {
            <li class="breadcrumb-item text-sm"><a class="opacity-5 text-dark" href="/"><i class="fa fa-home text-primary"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item text-sm text-dark active" aria-content="page">@Module.Humanize()</li>
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Module) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Function))
        {
            <li class="breadcrumb-item text-sm"><a class="opacity-5 text-dark" href="/"> <i class="fa fa-home text-primary"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item text-sm"><a class="opacity-5 text-dark" href="/@Module">@Module.Humanize()</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item text-sm text-dark active" aria-current="page">@Function.Humanize()</li>
        }
    </ol>
</nav>
@code {
    protected string? Module{ get; set; }
    protected string? Function{ get; set; }
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Navigation.LocationChanged += (object? sender,LocationChangedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            ChangeLink();
        };
    }
    protected void ChangeLink()
    {
        var Parameters = Navigation.ToBaseRelativePath(Navigation.Uri).Split('/');
        if (Parameters.Length > 1)
        {
            Module = Parameters[0];
            Function = Parameters[1];
        }
        else if (Parameters.Length > 0)
        {
            Module = Parameters[0];
            Function = string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            Module = string.Empty;
            Function = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a `StateHasChanged()` at the end of the method.

Comment: @MisterMagoo I'm not using async void. Can you please elaborate it more what are you saying?

Comment: You are correct - I misread your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `StateHasChanged()` at the end of your handler method as the event you're subscribing to is a .NET `EventHandler` delegate, specifically `EventHandler<LocationChangedEventArgs>` event.

These events do not automatically call `StateHasChanged()` thereby, notifying the UI that the component has changed and needs to rerender. Unlike the Blazor `EventCallback` events, which do.